# How to pass arguments in express.js

Tags: node.js, express, rpc, bitcoin-testnet

kind of a noob question, hopefully someone can help me with.

I am making an application which uses express.js to communicate with bitcoin-core by sending http reqests.

```
router.get("/getbalance", (req, res) => {
var dataString = `{"jsonrpc":"1.0","id":"curltext","method":"getbalance","params":[]}`;
var options = {
    url: `http://${USER}:${PASS}@127.0.0.1:18443/`,
    method: "POST",
    headers: headers,
    body: dataString
};

callback = (error, response, body) => {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        const data = JSON.parse(body);
        res.send(data);
    }
};
request(options, callback);
```

So far it is working quite well, and the problem arises when i try to pass more than one argument to the request, e.g., when i try to send bitcoin to an address in the console, the command is:

`bitcoin-cli -regtest sendtoaddress [someaddress] [amount]`

i tried to do it like this:

`http://localhost:4444/api/sendtoaddress/bcrt1q3nczv7jr88rwvhsyv2rx49l3czfxurzfk240ue/10`

but it just freezes.

This is what the "sendtoaddress" request looks like so far.

```
router.get("/sendtoaddress/:addr/:amount", (req, res) => {
var dataString = `{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id": "curltext", "method": "sendtoaddress", "params": [${req.params.addr}, ${req.params.amount}]}`
console.log(req.params.addr)
var options = {
    url: `http://${USER}:${PASS}@127.0.0.1:18443/`,
    method: "POST",
    headers: headers,
    body: dataString
};
callback = (error, response, body) => {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        const data = JSON.parse(body);
        res.send(data);
    }
};
request(options, callback);
```

Comment: not tested, but is most likely this part `"params": [${req.params.addr}, ${req.params.amount}]`, addr will be a string so it needs wrapping in quotes, instead of making a json string, make an object then json.stringify it. are you aware there is libs on npm for this. https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=bitcoin if your going to roll your own don't use a deprecated HTTP lib like requests

Comment: i just wrapped the address in quotes, works like a charm! thank you

Comment: np, you should still not directly place vars into json string else it could break, do it like https://playcode.io/979664

Answer (score 0):

As I'm a new contributor so can't create a comment.
it would be better if u could use query method to get the data from the url.

A basic get url would look like this:

```
"https://xyc.com/vehicle?name="abc"&color="color"
```

query method is used to get the fields after the `?`

We use `req.params` to get the `:id` from the url.

you can try changing your get url from this:

```
"/sendtoaddress/:addr/:amount"
```

to this:

```
"/sendtoaddress/:addr?amount="some_amount"
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This might work, but as Lawrence pointed out, by wrapping it in quotes, did the trick, thanks for you solution tho